# Почему bitset обнуляется

Tags: c++, указатели

Я хочу по битам считать определенную область памяти, первый вариант работает, второй - нет, хотя делает почти то же самое.

```
bitset<32> *readInt(unsigned int num) {
   bitset<32> *b = new(&num) bitset<32>;
   return  b;
}


int main()
{
    bitset<32> *a = readInt(12345);
    cout << *a << endl;
    // output: 00000000000000000011000000111001


    unsigned int num = 12345;
    bitset<32> *b = new(&num) bitset<32>;
    cout << *b << endl;
    // output: 00000000000000000000000000000000

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не работают оба варианта. Объект `unsigned int` не может использоваться для предоставления места объекту `bitset<32>`. Конструкция placement new должна создавать новый объект, дефолтный конструктор которого обнуляет все биты, а не считать что-то по битам. Функция `readInt` вообще возвращает битый указатель на локальную переменную.

Получайте доступ к object storage и вручную печатайте его содержимое по битам.